# Repartir Lista en tupla de listas (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, programación-funcional

Tenemos la siguiente función :

```
repartir [a] -> ([a],[a])
```

De forma que repartir debe repartir la lista principal en dos listas cogiendo los elementos de esta forma :

```
repartir [1,2,3,4,5]

---> ([1,3,5],[2,4])

repartir "hola"

---> ("hl","oa")
```

Solo podemos importar : `import Data.List`

Un saludo y gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma directa:

```
repartir :: [a] -> ([a],[a])
repartir xs = ([xs!!i | i <- [0,2..n]], [xs!!i | i <- [1,3..n]])
    where n = length xs - 1
```

El operador `!!` no es muy eficiente en listas, por lo que no hay que abusar de él. Una versión más eficaz:

```
repartir :: [a] -> ([a],[a])
repartir xs = ([x | (i,x) <- zs, odd i], [x | (i,x) <- zs, even i])
    where zs = zip [1..] xs
```

PD: no ha hecho falta importar el módulo `Data.List` ya que las funciones necesarias están incluidas en el `Prelude`

---

Existe una solución mejor usando tipos `Either`. Lo malo es que necesita importar el módulo `Data.Either`:

```
import Data.Either (partitionsEithers)

repartir :: [a] -> ([a],[a])
repartir = partitionEithers . zipWith id (cycle [Left,Right])
```

Answer (score 2):

Una solución más eficiente, sin utilizar funciones del módulo `Data.List` y recorriendo una sóla vez la lista, puede ser esta:

```
repartir :: [a] -> ([a],[a])
repartir = repartir' True

repartir' :: Bool -> [a] -> ([a],[a])
repartir' _ [] = ([],[])
repartir' g (x:xs) = let (a,b) = repartir' (not g) xs in if g then (x:a,b) else (a,x:b)
```

Answer (score 1):

En estos casos lo mejor es ir paso a paso simplificando el problema.

El reparto lo puedes ver como dos casos separados (los dos elementos de la tupla). El primero se lleva dos de la lista descartando el segundo y el segundo de la tupla se lleva también dos pero descartando el primero.

Para el primero:

```
reparte1 :: [a] -> [a]                       -- firma
reparte1 (x:_:xs) = x : reparte1 xs          -- tomo el 1ro, descarto el 2do
```

Pero...

```
*Main> reparte1 "hola"
"hl*** Exception: Non-exhaustive patterns in function reparte1
```

Falta lo obvio, el caso de cierre. Ahora sería:

```
reparte1 :: [a] -> [a]                       -- firma
reparte1 [] = []                             -- fin
reparte1 (x:_:xs) = x : reparte1 xs          -- tomo el 1ro, descarto el 2do
```

Ahora falla en impares:

```
*Main> reparte1 "hola"
"hl"
*Main> reparte1 "holas"
"hl*** Exception: Non-exhaustive patterns in function reparte1
```

Fácil de solucionar. Agregas este caso:

```
reparte1 :: [a] -> [a]                       -- firma
reparte1 [] = []                             -- fin
reparte1 [x] = [x]                           -- cuando quede uno me lo quedo
reparte1 (x:_:xs) = x : reparte1 xs          -- tomo el 1ro, descarto el 2do

*Main> reparte1 "hola"
"hl"
*Main> reparte1 "holas"
"hls"
```

El caso 2 es igual pero descartas el primer elemento y te quedas con el segundo. Con cantidad impar de elementos lo ignoras.

```
reparte2 :: [a] -> [a]                       -- firma
reparte2 [] = []                             -- fin
reparte2 [x] = []                            -- cuando quede uno lo ignoro
reparte2 (_:x:xs) = x : reparte2 xs          -- descarto el 1ro, tomo el 2do

*Main> reparte2 "holas"
"oa"
```

Y finalmente juntas los dos casos.

```
repartir :: [a] -> ([a],[a])
repartir (x) = (reparte1 x, reparte2 x)

*Main> repartir [1,2,3,4,5]
([1,3,5],[2,4])
*Main> repartir "hola"
("hl","oa")
```

La optimización queda a cargo del alumno. ;-)